# Not properly calling a Stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

I have an oracle stored procedure which is working fine on sqldeveloper inserting record.
How can i call it from asp.net? I have seen other solutions as well not helpfull.

```
OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection(_db.ConnectionString);
 objConn.Open();
 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERTDOCUMENT", objConn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("TMPLT_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = _schema.ID;
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
objConn.Close();
```

Someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'RMI_PR.INSERTDOCUMENT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is proper?

Comment: yes connection string is fine i am using it everywhere.

Comment: Are you using the same user like in SQL Developer. The error says that it cannot find the INSERTDOCUMENT, which means it doesn't exist or is invisible or your user has no right to call it. If it is invisible to the user, make public synonym, otherwise grant execute right on the procedure to the necessary user.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the stored procedure INSERTDOCUMENT is in the oracle schema "'RMI_PR".

Convert the statement
 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERTDOCUMENT", objConn);
into 
 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("RMI_PR.INSERTDOCUMENT", objConn);